# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging store messages on FCM server?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does Firebase Cloud Messaging store messages on FCM server?

I am using FCM to send push notification in my mobile app (Android + iOS). I have a query regarding data security. Does FCM stores notification data on their server?